# How to position static buttons and iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on an app where i have 12 buttons and labels underneath on one of the views.  They are placed on the storyboard directly.  I want to make sure they will get properly repositioned in iPhone 5. The solution that i tried is just to deselect all the lines in the autosizing for all the buttons.  Now when i try it on iphone 5 the buttons get resized. The problem if i stretch the storyboard and move the buttons they get messed up when running on the smaller screen. So i can only position them on the smaller screen and then it seems to work.  The app does not rotate.  I would like to know if this is a good solution or there is a better solution for this case.  I would like for the app to support iOS 5+

Thank you!

Comment: turn off the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` or `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` bits of `autoresizingMask`, you can do it in the _Interface Builder_ or programmatically as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want layouts to work with varying screen sizes, you should become familiar with the new constraint-based layout scheme in iOS 6. A WWDC video on the subject can be viewed at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkr9eKxlMAk&feature=player_detailpage.

Essentially, you're going to use the old struts and springs system for pre-iOS 5 and conditionally use the new scheme for iOS 6. (iPhone 5 won't run any iOS version prior to 6.)